# How can I select and delete the left track of a stereo recording in Logic Pro X

Tags: stereo, logic-pro, mono, audio-editor

I have a simple question about the audio editor from Logic Pro X.
After recording some ambience of a outdoor scene I've seen that I was recording the scene in stereo. I used only one microphone which means that there is a "flatline" channel now which I would like to get rid of.

To achieve this in some audio editors (i.e. Audition) I simply selected the left or right channel by moving the mouse to the top or bottom of the channel and then I could edit only the mono track. By hitting "delete" it was gone and the whole sample turned into a mono track.

How is ist possible to

1. Edit only the left or right channel of a stereo recording
2. Delete one channel completely from a stereo recording

in Logic Pro X?

Thanks in advance

Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the bottom of the Channel Strip section. 
Here you will find a Format button that shows if the track is stereo or mono (there is a two-circle icon indicating it is stereo):

[image]

or

[image]

Click-hold the button and select either Left or Right channel:

[image]

Additional details in [the manual](https://documentation.apple.com/en/logicpro/usermanual/Logic%20Pro%209%20User%20Manual%20(en).pdf) around page 264-265.

Note that if you want to physically change the file format, you need to bounce a split stereo PCM, reimport one of the channels, delete the other (and the original stereo file and track).

Comment: Thank you so much. In logic pro x there is another button: http://imgur.com/GYuTVjT  This "Button" is a split button. Which means that the stereo symbol on the left side pops out another menu then the right area of that button. Your answer and screenshots helped me seeing this. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JackPearse Cool - I added your image to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is set the output of your stereo track to a stereo bus, let's say Bus 1-2. Then create two mono audio tracks and set one's input to Bus 1 and the other's to Bus 2 and record the entire track. Hard pan L and R these two mono tracks and edit them as you please!